# IE 8 "alt" tag wont render when mouseover?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

Ok.  I have a fieldset menu.  If I hardcode the last item the alt works:

```
<td>
                        <a href="show.hotpartslist?clearFilters=true">
                            <img class="icon" title="Clear All Filters" alt="Clear All Filters" src="../images/clear_all.gif"/>
                        </a>
                    </td>
```

But this one is built with some logic and it renders like this:

```
<td>
                        <ul id="hp-sor-menu" style="display:none;"><li><img alt="Filter by Source of Repair" src="../images/sor.gif" /><ul><li><a href="show.hotpartslist?sor=ALL">&#8594;&nbsp;&nbsp;ALL</a></li><li><a href="show.hotpartslist?sor=A">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;MCA</a></li><li><a href="show.hotpartslist?sor=B">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;MCB</a></li><li><a href="show.hotpartslist?sor=E">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;BIC</a></li><li><a href="show.hotpartslist?sor=O">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;OTHER</a></li></ul></li></ul><script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function()
{
    try
    {

        DynarchMenu.setup('hp-sor-menu', {  });

    }
    catch(exception)
    {
        alert("Failed to render other menu: " + exception.description);
    }
});
```

And the alt does not display when mosueover

Comment: I would recommend trying title="CONTENT", alt="CONTENT" is meant for when the image does not load. In your hard coded version, you have title, yet I don't see it in the generated version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its the title attribute that causes the mouseover effect. You dont have that attribute populated.

Comment: Old browser versions used to display the content of `alt` attributes, that's why some still mistakenly only set that one instead of the `title` attribute. So, marteljn is absolutely right.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `title` attribute for the `mouseover` to show a tooltip.  The `alt` tag is only for displaying text when the image doesn't load, although it is often co-opted by SEO companies to make pages rank better.